# Find the partials $\frac{\partial z} {\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ with $z$ defined implicitly as a function of $x$ and $y$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation

> Find the partials $\frac{\partial z} {\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ with $z$ defined implicitly as a function of $x$ and $y$

The equation is $3x^2z-x^2y^2+2z^3+3yz=5$

I'm confused as to how I should treat the third variable, $z$ when taking the partials.  Is this correct?

$\frac{\partial z} {\partial x}= 6xz-2xy^2+2z^3=5$

$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = -2x^2y+2z^3+3z=5$

Comment: You should treat $z$ as you would in implicit differentiation.  Therefore, you'll need a $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ every time a $z$ appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are thinking of $z$ as a function of $x$ and $y$, you could write $z=z(x,y)$.  Then, when you take a partial derivative with respect to $x$, you must think of $y$ as fixed and study how $z$ changes as you change $x$.  In particular, you must use the rules of implicit differentiation:

Starting with:
$$3x^2z-x^2y^2+2z^3+3yz=5$$
take the derivative of both sides with respect to $x$ to get
$$
6xz+3x^2\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}-2xy^2+6z^2\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+3y\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=0.
$$
Now, solve for $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ by factoring and dividing by the coefficient.

Comment: Thanks for this solution.  I'm confused as to how you obtained the derivative above.  So for the first term I see that you simply took the derivative of $z$ with respect to $x$, so $z$ was treated as a constant.  The second term confuses me, you wrote the first equation again and replaced the $z$ with the $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$?  I haven't done implicit differentiation in 3 years so I forgot how to do it.

Comment: Never mind, I understand!  I did a little implicit differentiation refresher.

Comment: This is what I got for the other one (haven't factored yet and solved for the partial.  $3x^2\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}-2x^2y+6z^2\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}+3y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}+3z=0$

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: I get the same result as you but when I let my calculator do the work it gets an answer very similar to ours but drops the single $y$.  $\frac{2x(-3x+y^2)}{3(x^2+2z^2+y)}$ is what I get but the calculator gets this: $\frac{2x(-3x+y^2)}{3(x^2+2z^2)}$.  Why?

Comment: Did you check what you entered into your calculator - maybe there was a typo?

Comment: Yup, I double and triple checked.  I'll do it once more for good measure.